# What is the delete statement if i using Oracle database?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-delete

when i write code to delete data in the row of my table  it didn't delete

this my code `

```
SQL> select * from bill;

   PID        TID    BILL_NO       CODE                                     

     1          1          5          2                                     
     1          2          3                                                

SQL> delete from bill where bill_no in(5,3);

2 rows deleted.

SQL> select * from bill;

no rows selected

SQL> spool off;
SQL> select * from bill;

   PID        TID    BILL_NO       CODE                                     

     1          1          5          2                                     
     1          2          3                                                

SQL> spool off;`
```

what is the problem ?
by the way i am beginner in oracle

Comment: Your changes weren't committed!

delete from bill where bill_no in(5,3);
commit;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle and other relational databases support transactions. Transactions mean that you either have to commit your changes or roll them back, done with the `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK` command respectively. Usually programs execute an implicit `ROLLBACK` on exit of similar activity as well as the Oracle Database issues a `ROLLBACK` on outstanding changes on a disconnect.

```
SQL> select * from bill;

PID        TID    BILL_NO       CODE                                     

 1          1          5          2                                     
 1          2          3                                                

SQL> delete from bill where bill_no in(5,3);

2 rows deleted.

SQL> COMMIT;
```

Comment: You are welcome! You can also look at http://livesql.oracle.com for further tutorials and a playground.

Answer (score 4):

DML commands need to be committed:

```
  commit;
```